# "Close >> migrate to another SE" : please add Physics SE and Biology SE as options

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, migration

When we vote to close a question, one of the options is to move the question to another Stack Exchange. But the only one listed is Meta.Worldbuilding. The two I most frequently wish were there are Physics SE and Biology SE.

I would like us to add both of those as options for question migration.

Comment: The mods of this site can post statistics of how many questions get migrated to Physics or Biology, and how many of those migrations are accepted by the target site. I do know there are very few migrations to Physics, possibly not enough to justify a migration path. Can you offer any examples of questions here which you would have liked to migrate to those other sites if the option were available?

Comment: I'm curious if this would get used much at all... We have so many questions that are on the edge of plausible, and most of the other exchanges don't want questions about things that are speculation. I really doubt that Biology would welcome a question about animals that photosynthesize (as an example).

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261196/274942, http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2769/627.

Comment: I would point to Monica's answer here:  I think this is the way to go personally:  http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/2811/189

Answer (score 5):

I'm just adding some data, so people have an idea of the actual migration activity that's happened on Worldbuilding throughout its history. Here are some stats on how many questions we've migrated to various sites, after a quick manual count (so maybe assume these numbers are $\pm$ 1). In no order:

- Physics: 7
- Writers: 4
- Earth Science: 3
- Philosophy: 2
- English Language and Usage: 3
- Space Exploration: 3
- Game Development: 1
- Astronomy: 12
- Science Fiction and Fantasy: 3
- Christianity: 1
- Politics: 1
- Biology: 1
- Worldbuilding Meta: 11
- History: 4
- Movies and TV: 2
- Mythology: 1
- Stack Overflow: 1
- Law: 2
- Bitcoin: 1
- Mathematics: 1
- Health: 1
- Martial Arts: 1
- Cognitive Sciences: 2
- Role-playing Games: 3
- English Language Learners: 1
- Engineering: 2
- Super User: 1
- Freelancing: 1
- Home Improvement: 1
- Pets: 1

I know what you're thinking: We migrated as many questions to *Freelancing* as we did to Biology? Yes we did. And [the one question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/46375/627) we sent to Biology was rejected, while [the one on Freelancing](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/2692) was better received.

Looking at this list - and ignoring Worldbuilding Meta, since we have a default path there - the top targets are, in order:

- Astronomy (12)
- Physics (7)
- Writers/History (4 apiece)

I don't have data on rejected migrations yet, but [one question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/61059/627) was rejected by the target site, which was Physics. For the most part, the migrations are successful.

Comment: I didn't even know migrations actually happened because I thought only the "Close >> migrate" was the reason a migration would occur. Are these migrations the result of a diamond user just deciding to do it? I generally leave a comment when I think something should migrate. Should we have been raising moderator flags on this issue? (I'm very reluctant to raise moderator flags... I've been trained to use them only when absolutely nothing else will do.)

Comment: @SRM Currently the process is - 90% of the time - 1) User flags question to be migrated elsewhere. 2) Moderator either migrates question, declines the flag, or asks a mod on that site if it's good to send over. 3) Question goes to new site or stays on Worldbuilding. I'll be honest, though: [question migration is sort of broken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285467/274942).

Comment: @SRM What HDE said; a diamond moderator can migrate a question to any site, regardless of whether an established migration path exists or not. That can be done in response to a flag, in response to noticing a discussion in comments (or in chat), or on the moderator's own initiative.

Comment: I'm not surprised Biology SE rejected the question. But I am surprised by the one Physics SE rejected, that seems their area. Oh well! It's their choice.

Comment: I'm surprised writers is so low given the nature of the sites

Comment: @Separatrix Writers is quite strict on their guidelines and a lot of questions that don't fit here also don't fit there. (For example see http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/136/is-a-help-me-generate-plot-ideas-or-similar-question-on-topic )

Answer (score 2):

I quite like having the moderator "filter" on migrations for two reasons.

1. We don't want a reputation for sending off-topic rubbish to other sites and people who know about our site don't necessarily know what is on topic for other sites.

   For example I've seen quite a few flags or comments suggesting a migration to writers for questions that I know for a fact would be off topic there.

   As moderators we always have the option of checking with the moderators of the target site before migrating, that's not so easy for a regular user to do.
2. Some people are far too keen to send perfectly good worldbuilding questions to other sites just because it is also on topic there.

If you see a question that belongs on another site flag it for a moderator and we'll take a look. The more automated migration flow is only needed if we see a large increase in migrations to a specific target and can be sure that our community knows what is on and off topic for that target.

Comment: A VTC doesn't automigrate, does it?

Comment: We don't use it here (so I'm not an expert) but my understanding is that a successful close vote as belonging on another site will indeed auto-migrate.

Comment: HDE implied that the migration still required diamond intervention. Is there documentation somewhere? If not, is there any way to try a test question?

Comment: @SRM If there is no defined migration path (i.e. nothing appears in the close list for standard users) then migration requires a moderator. If a defined migration path is present then 5 users with sufficient rep can trigger a migration along that path. Migrations to sites not on that list still require a moderator.

Comment: Cool. That's what I hoped. Now to get a couple more sites added to that list. I know you don't like that, but I think it would be a good change.